# Best practices with saving settings data

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a main class which on user event shows the settings window. There are some textboxes, radiobuttons etc. After pressing the Save button, I want to store the data to some file.

I think that the saving process should be inside the main class and settings window only takes care of displaying the current config data, validate the new data and then send them back to the main class. Is this right?

How can I "send" the current config data from main class (which knows where the config file is etc.) to the window and then "send" the new data from window to main class to be stored?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In WPF you can use `Properties.Settings` (Best solution for storing any application settings). [See this.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a65txexh(v=VS.110).aspx)

Or you can create your own settings file, as an example, you may create xml file, and store your data into it.

See:

- [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [DataContractSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)